# My xcode10 version has been updated , i don't find any simulator. It is only marked on Generic IOS Device

Tags: xcode10

In my Xcode10.3 version it only shows "Generic IOS device". No simulator is not shown here In the set the active scheme property.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xcode 10.3 Installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57155654/xcode-10-3-installation)

Comment: I Have solve this issue through restarting my PC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common problem when you will try to make application in xcode from MacBook Air. To solve this problem close the application. Then restart your your PC. Hope, it would solve the problem.