# Storyboard broken after updating Xcode to version 10.3 (10G8) & app no longer is running

Tags: xcode, storyboard

I just updated the Xcode to version 10.3 (10G8).

Now my project is not run with this error:
[image]

```
/* com.apple.actool.errors */
: error: Failed to find a suitable device for the type IBSimDeviceTypeiPad2x (com.apple.dt.Xcode.IBSimDeviceType.iPad-2x) with runtime iOS 12.4 (12.4 - 16G73) - com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-12-4
    Failure Reason: Failed to create new simulator device that matches IBSimDeviceTypeiPad2x (com.apple.dt.Xcode.IBSimDeviceType.iPad-2x) for runtime iOS 12.4 (12.4 - 16G73) - com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-12-4 (Invalid runtime: com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-12-4)
    Underlying Errors:
        Description: Invalid runtime: com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-12-4
/* com.apple.actool.compilation-results */
/Users/xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xxxxx-dxlvvymxzdfqjubnuntqlxggtyja/Build/Intermediates.noindex/xxxxx.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/xxxxx.build/assetcatalog_generated_info.plist
```

And the storyboard is now like this:
[image]

Comment: [Same issue of this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57155654/xcode-10-3-installation) Hope it helps you ~~:)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57172619/firebaseui-phoneauth-firebasephoneauthui-fuicodefield-xib-1-failed-to-find-or I have a similar problem

Answer (score 87, accepted):

I restarted my mac, the problem solved.

Comment: This solution also works if you cannot see simulators after the update.

Comment: But, It does not fix the "Release Notes" and the "What's New in Xcode" menus from sending you to https://localhost 

Comment: the #1 issue I had on Windows+Visual Studio has now appeared on my Mac...

Comment: Who would have thought a one line answer (_looks more like comment to me_) would get so many upvotes.. :)

Answer (score 90):

Running `sudo killall -9 com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimulatorService` from terminal solved my problem.

Comment: @rmaddy, this is a better answer than the accepted answer

Comment: WOW! That worked like magic! Thanks for your time and effort!

Comment: yep, worked for me. had to restart Xcode after the killall9

Comment: Worked perfectly for me and it means I don't have to reboot my machine.  Thanks!

Comment: OMG this is a JEWEL of an answer! I was freaking out over a project that is going through a SWIFT rewrite — I was this close to redesigning all of the storyboards. You saved me time and effort.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, all i did is

clear constraint, for my case the source was from UITableView, and make sure constraints are attached to safeare not superview. [see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cUnjt.png)

from toolbar on the top go to Editor > Canvas > Layout Rectangle Very important you have to repeat this step 3 times

Quit XCode and reopen it again , all should be fixed

I've noticed this happen when i switch view for different devices 8, 11, 4s

Good luck