# FirebaseUI/PhoneAuth/FirebasePhoneAuthUI/FUICodeField.xib:-1: Failed to find or create execution context for description

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, firebaseui

After updating Xcode to `10.3` I get the bellow error (which I see has something to do with firebase):

[image]

The page which accompanies it is: 
[image]

**Why is this error happening and how can I fix it?**

What I have tried:

- updating pods
- restarting Xcode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this after looking at the answer on this question: [Storyboard broken after updating Xcode to version 10.3 (10G8) & app no longer is running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57156617/storyboard-broken-after-updating-xcode-to-version-10-3-10g8-app-no-longer-is?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Restarted the mac, problem solved.